# Razor menu code inserts blank list items, Can anyone spot why please?

Tags: c#, razor

I am working on a dynamic menu and the code below in a view works fine, generates the menu & sub menus all ok. BUT it inserts an extra empty li after each "top level" item. I have tried breaking it up into smaller chunks but no go. Can anyone spot why please??

The generated html:

#

```
    <ul>
<li class="stylename1">
<a target="" href="/">Home</a>
</li>
<li> </li>
<li class="active stylename">
<a target="" href="/other_page">other_page</a>
<div class="submenubox">
<ul>
</div>
</li>
<li> </li>
```

#### the view code:

```
    <ul>     
@foreach (var item in MenuHelper.Top()) 
{     
   if (item.Navigation.Show) 
   {  
     currstream = item.Layout;    

    switch (currstream)
    {
    case "Home":
        currstyle = "style-a";
        break;
    case "Information_Home":
         currstyle = "style-b";   
        break;          
    default:
        currstyle = "style-c";
        break;
   }

   foreach (var subItem in MenuHelper.Sub(item)) 
   { 
     submenucount++; 
   }   

    if (submenucount > 0)     
    { 
      @:<li class ='@(MenuHelper.IsCurrent(item) ? "active" : "") @currstyle'>@Html.FrontHtml().PageLink(item.LinkText, item.FullName) <div class='submenubox' ><ul > 

                foreach (var subItem in MenuHelper.Sub(item)) 
             {     

               if (item.Navigation.Show) 
               { 
                <li class ='@(MenuHelper.IsCurrent(subItem) ? "active" : "") @currstyle'>@Html.FrontHtml().PageLink(subItem.LinkText, subItem.FullName)</li> 
               } 

             } 

    @:</ul></div><li> 

   } 
   else 
   { 
     @:<li class ='@(MenuHelper.IsCurrent(item) ? "active" : "") @currstyle'>@Html.FrontHtml().PageLink(item.LinkText, item.FullName)<li> 
   }   

   submenucount = 0; 
  } 

 } 

</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're not closing your tags correctly, you're appending another `<li>` instead of the closing `</li>`. Try this:

```c#
if (submenucount > 0)     
{ 
    @:<li class ='@(MenuHelper.IsCurrent(item) ? "active" : "") @currstyle'>@Html.FrontHtml().PageLink(item.LinkText, item.FullName) <div class='submenubox'><ul> 

    foreach (var subItem in MenuHelper.Sub(item)) 
    {     
        if (item.Navigation.Show) 
        { 
            <li class ='@(MenuHelper.IsCurrent(subItem) ? "active" : "") @currstyle'>@Html.FrontHtml().PageLink(subItem.LinkText, subItem.FullName)</li> 
        } 
    } 
    @:</ul></div></li> @* Note /li here *@
} 
else 
{ 
    @:<li class ='@(MenuHelper.IsCurrent(item) ? "active" : "") @currstyle'>@Html.FrontHtml().PageLink(item.LinkText, item.FullName)<li> @* Note /li here *@
}
```

Comment: More I look at something the blinder I get! Thanks for the help Rory.

Comment: @user1295445 I know the feeling :) Glad to help.